# A linear function involving the global optimum of the Rayleigh quotient

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given $\mathbf{A}$ is a real symmetric matrix. The leading eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $\mathbf{A}$ is equal to:
$$\lambda_1 = max_{||\mathbf{x}||=1} \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x},$$
where the eigenvector $\mathbf{v}_1$ associated with $\lambda_1$ is the optimum of the above optimization:
$$\mathbf{v}_1 = argmax_{||\mathbf{x}||=1} \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}.$$
Define $t:=\mathbf{v}_1^T \mathbf{c}$, where $\mathbf{c}$ is a real vector with constants. I know $\lambda_1$ is a convex function of $\mathbf{A}$ by the Courant-Fisher Theorem. I am wondering if $t$ is a convex/concave function of $\mathbf{A}$? Is there a principled way to analyze the relations between $t$ and $\mathbf{A}$?

Answer (score 0):

I think this function is not a convex or concave function of $\mathbf{A}$ since the eigenvector will change a lot even with a small perturbation.

Consider $\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and 
$
\mathbf{B} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \delta \\
\delta & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$ for small $\delta > 0$. Then, the first eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}$ is $(1,0)$, while the first eigenvector of $\mathbf{B}$ is $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$. Taking $c = (0,1)$, you can find a counterexample.